# Spring boot controller content negotiation

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I have a simple REST controller written in a Spring-boot application but I am not sure how to implement the content negotiation to make it return JSON or XML based on the Content-Type parameter in the request header. Could someone explain to me, what am I doing wrong?

Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/message", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
  public Message getMessageXML(@RequestParam("text") String text) throws Exception {
    Message message = new Message();
    message.setDate(new Date());
    message.setName("Test");
    message.setAge(99);
    message.setMessage(text);

    return message;
  }
```

I always get JSON when calling this method (even if I specify the `Content-Type` to be `application/xml` or `text/xml`).

When I implement two methods each with different mapping and different content type, I am able to get XML from the xml one but it does not work if I specify two mediaTypes in a single method (like the provided example).

What I would like is to call the `\message` endpoint and receive

- XML when the Content-Type of the GET request is set to application/xml
- JSON when the Content-Type is application/json

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
I updated my controller to accept all media types

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/message", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE }, consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
  public Message getMessageXML(@RequestParam("text") String text) throws Exception {
    Message message = new Message();
    message.setDate(new Date());
    message.setName("Vladimir");
    message.setAge(35);
    message.setMessage(text);

    return message;
  }
```

Comment: You need to provide an `Accept` header with the value `application/xml` or with any of the supported media types.

Comment: The "Content-Type" header defines which type of content you're sending - not which you want to receive (that's what the "Accept" header is for. So using the "Content-Type" header for a GET request doesn't make sense, since can't have any (body) content.
So in your case you should use the "Accept" header for your request and in the response the "Content-Type" header to name the type of content that is actually send.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can find some hints in the blog post [@RequestMapping with Produces and Consumes](https://www.dineshonjava.com/using-consumes-and-produces-to/) at point 6.

Pay attention to the section about Content-Type and Accept headers:

> @RequestMapping with Produces and Consumes: We can use header
> Content-Type and Accept to find out request contents and what is the
> mime message it wants in response. For clarity, @RequestMapping
> provides produces and consumes variables where we can specify the
> request content-type for which method will be invoked and the response
> content type. For example:
>
> ```
> @RequestMapping(value="/method6", produces={"application/json","application/xml"}, consumes="text/html")
> @ResponseBody
> public String method6(){
>     return "method6";
> }
> ```
>
> Above method can consume message only with Content-Type as text/html
> and is able to produce messages of type application/json and
> application/xml.

You can also try [this](http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-mvc-requestmapping-consumes-condition-example) different approach (using ResponseEntity object) that allows you to find out the incoming message type and produce the corresponding message (also exploiting the @ResponseBody annotation)

Answer (score 41):

You can use [ContentNegotiationConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ContentNegotiationConfigurer.html)

Firstly, you should override the `configureContentNegotiation` method in your configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.favorPathExtension(false).
            favorParameter(true).
            defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
            mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    }
}
```

`favorParameter(true)` - enabling favoring path expressions over parameter or accept headers.

`defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` - sets the default content type. this means that if you don't pass a path expression then Spring will generate JSON as response.

`mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)` - sets the path expression key for XML.

Now if you declare your Controller like:

```
@Controller
class AccountController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/accounts", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public @ResponseBody List<Account> list(Model model, Principal principal) {
        return accountManager.getAccounts(principal) );
    }
}
```

and call it something like `localhost:8080/app/accounts.json`, then Spring will generate JSON as response. So if you call `localhost:8080/app/accounts.xml` you will receive XML response

You can find more info about this [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc).

Comment: just a little footnote on the defaultContentType: [browsers tend to send accept headers that prefer XML](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html).  
Bypassing (assuming your aren't using it) the Accept header can be done in your override of contentNegotiation:  
`configurer.ignoreAcceptHeader(true)`

Comment: I think there is a minor mistake here - the way you claim the controller to work, you should be setting favorPathExtension to be true, rather than favorParameter.

Comment: Another little footnote: in a Spring boot application, your `@Configuration` class should **not** contain the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation ([source](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-enablewebmvc-and-common-use-cases)). It may prevent other things from working, such as the springfox-swagger-ui html page.

Comment: Use `implements WebMvcConfigurer` instead of the deprecated `extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` for current spring boot versions.

Answer (score 0):

Side note: In Spring Boot 2.6 and later, the path file extension strategy (e.g. `/resource.xml`) for content negotiation is deprecated, and so it might not be future proof to depend on it for new applications. The format parameter strategy (e.g. `/resource?format=xml`) also seems to be disabled by default. To enable the format parameter strategy, add a configuration class:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig
  implements WebMvcConfigurer
{
  @Override
  public void configureContentNegotiation( ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer )
  {
    configurer
      .favorParameter( true );
  }
}
```

Also note that since Java 8, the `WebMvcConfigurer` interface has default methods and configuration classes can implement it directly without subclassing `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`.