# Can I configure both HTML and Spring Data REST JSON on the same URI?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I am writing a web application with Spring MVC.

Keeping with REST principles, I am wanting to use consistent URIs in my application for the same resources and to use content negotation to select whether to return HTML or JSON. Visiting `/people/bob` in a browser should show his profile page, and getting it with `curl` should give me a JSON representation.

However, [because of a semantic limitation (bug?) in the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14762), I can't "fall through" to the generic Spring Data REST mappings if I define any explicit controller, such as an HTML controller, on a matching URI. Besides manually implementing a `@RestRepositoryController` for every matching HTML controller, is there any other simple way to make Spring MVC content-negotiate between HTML and JSON mappings?

---

*Example mapping that doesn't work:*

```
@BasePathAwareController
class PersonHtmlController {
    @GetMapping(path = '/people/{id}', produces = 'text/html')
    ModelAndView person(@PathVariable Person id) {
        new ModelAndView('person', [person: id])
    }
}
```

This produces the expected HTML output but returns a 406 Not Acceptable when I ask for JSON.

Comment: Have you tried to override `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter$configureContentNegotiation`, as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33010537/5873923)? (Another example is available [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-content-negotiation-json-xml)).

Comment: @MarcTarin That's all properly autoconfigured by Boot.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for [contentnegotiatingviewresolver](https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc). Following is an example.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView userDetails() {

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    List userDetails = userService.getUserDetails();
    modelAndView.addObject("users", userDetails);
    modelAndView.setViewName("userDetails");
    return modelAndView;

}
```

So whenever a request comes with `/users` then html page will be served and when the request comes as `/users.json` then a JSON response will be generated.

You can configure it in following way by overriding following method by extending WebMvcConfigurerAdapter provided by Spring.

```
@Override
public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {

    registry.jsp("/WEB-INF/jsp/", ".jsp").viewClass(JstlView.class);
    registry.enableContentNegotiation(
            new MappingJackson2JsonView()
    );

}
```

Hope this helps.
Reference:
[contentnegotiating view resolver example](http://www.devglan.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-contentnegotiating-viewresolver-example)

Comment: This is not relevant to the issue I'm asking about, which is the mapping stage, not view resolution.