# How to specify default media type for endpoints in a Spring Boot service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am building a Spring Boot service with several endpoints. My service needs to support both `json` and `xml` output. Most endpoints will be `json` only and some will be `xml` only. I can specify the content type a specific endpoint accepts or returns with annotation `@RequestMapping`. For example:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,
                consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE},
                produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
```

However, since most my application's endpoints will be `json` only, I wanted to avoid having to write

```
consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},
produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}
```

in all of them. Is there a way to make a method annotated with `@RequestMapping` have a default `consumes` and `produces` media type? Whenever I need something different from the default I can specify it.

I have tried setting up content negotiation but it doesn't apply to this. I think that I might be able to do it via content negotiation with a custom `ContentNegotiationStrategy` but I would need that code to be able to read the annotations of the handler for that request (the specific method annotated with `@RequestMapping`) and the code only gets a `NativeWebRequest`.

Is there a global Spring configuration for achieving this?

EDIT:
Setting content negotiation with

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
class ContentNegotiationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorParameter(false)
                  .favorPathExtension(true)
                  .ignoreAcceptHeader(true)
                  .ignoreUnknownPathExtensions(false)
                  .useJaf(false)
                  .defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }
}
```

and endpoint with

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

then calling the endpoint

```
GET https://localhost:8080/endpoint.xml
```

returns `xml` output and HTTP `200` instead of HTTP `406`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ContentNegotiationConfigurer it lets you specify the content type for the whole application. See this question: [Spring boot controller content negotiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33009918/spring-boot-controller-content-negotiation)

Comment: The edit doesn't change the initial question, which explicitly stated content negotiation would not do what I wanted :).

Comment: Hey two persons independently pointed you to the ContentNegotiationConfigurer. I am out now.

Answer (score 0):

Add this bean to your configuration:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class MyWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configureContentNegotiation (ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
      configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
  }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't do what you think it does. I will provide example.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this Java Configuration

```
public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.favorPathExtension(true).
    favorParameter(false).
    parameterName("mediaType").
    ignoreAcceptHeader(false).
    useJaf(false).
    defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
    mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML). 
    mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's all about what content type you return. If you define content negotiation like this:

```
@Override
public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer
            .favorPathExtension(false)
            .favorParameter(true)
            .mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
}
```

Then you can have a single method which processes different content types, for e.g.:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/process/{json}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> process(@PathVariable("json") boolean processJson) {
    if (processJson) {
        final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("someJSONObject", headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("someXMLObject", headers, HttpStatus.OK);   
    }
}
```

If you need to pass the objects directly to the response so that they would be serialized correctly you'll need to use message converters as well. For e.g.:

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper));
    converters.add(new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter(objectMapper));
}
```