# Produce 2 separate responses of different media types via same rest service

Tags: java, spring-boot

Is there any way, I can produce 2 separate responses of different media types via same rest service?

I have a service which consumes JSON and produces JSON.

Now I want the same method to produce either `byte[]` for pdf or `UserModel` so the definition is like

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getUser/{userId}",
    produces = {"application/pdf","application/json"},
    consumes = {"application/json"},
    method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<UserModel> getUser(@PathVariable("userId")String userId){

    //returns UserModel JSON 

    and can return
    //returns bye[] and I generate pdf from the stream
    }
```

How can I decide on the fly which one to generate since the API CALL hit pattern is same with same parameters. I can easily create another method to make it work but I want to know how can I achieve `produces = "application/pdf","application/json"},` in spring boot since both are completely different types.

Comment: Create two methods, mapped to the same URL and same HTTP method. One with produces=application/pdf, and the other with produces=application/json. One returns a UserModel, the other returns a byte array.

Comment: Is this a spring project? You can use the Accept header strategy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33009918/spring-boot-controller-content-negotiation
or here:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-content-negotiation-json-xml