# How to accept different type of request payload by single endpoint defined using sprint boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I would like my controller class to accept different type of RequestBody as part of a POST.
Consider I have an api say /download which is responsible to download bunch of reports (around 30) which has totally different payload. I don't want to create 30 different api's to handle it.
Is there any more simpler way which can be used to avoid this redundancy?

I have tried using below approach:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity download(@RequestBody JsonNode requestBody) {.. }

But, using this approach I am unable to generate API documentation using swagger.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring boot controller content negotiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33009918/spring-boot-controller-content-negotiation)

Comment: No, my question was totally opposite. I want to consume different types of request payload by single endpoint